# Check if key is in a generic - Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've been struggling to find out if a key of an object exists on a generic. I know types cannot be used as values so `typeof` and `instanceof` won't help here. I've tried various things using `keyof` with another generic like `K extends keyof TOutput -> TOutput[K]` but nothing has worked so far.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
const fn = <TSource extends Record<string, any>, TOutput extends Record<string, any>>(src: TSource) => {
        const output = {};

        for (const key in src) {
            const element = src[key];
            // if (< key is in keyof TOutput >) output[key] = element;
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Is there a way to get a key of a generic and use it in an if statement?

Comment: No, you need a value at runtime.

Comment: ^^ If you were looking for a key in `TSource`, of course you'd be good, but you have nothing at runtime to check for `TOutput`. Other than some aspects of enums, types don't exist at runtime, except as byproducts of characteristics of values.